# Given a graph $G = (V, E),$ prove that if $|E| > \binom{ |V| -1}{2}$ then the graph is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, advice

I know that a similar exercice was already posted on this website but I would like to have a piece of advice concerning the method/way of thinking I used to solve this problem. I don't know if I can do this here or if I have to write in the comment of the exercice that was posted. Pardon in advance.

---

We have to prove a statement $p \Rightarrow q.$ So as to do so I wanted to prove $\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p.$

To solve this problem I first considered that with a graph with $n$ vertices the maximum value of edges that we can get is when we consider the graph as a complete graph . But we have to deal with a disconnected graph. To obtain the maximal value of edges, I split the set of vertices into two partitions $X$ and $Y$ such that $Y$ = {v} where v $\in$ $V$. This would mean that $|X| = |V|-1.$

Now, I compute the maximum number of edges that I can obtain from the graph $X: \binom{|V| -1}{2}$. As it corresponds to the maximal value of edges that we can obtain (by respecting the conditions of the statement), it means that $|E| \leq \binom{|V| -1}{2}$.

Ps: I only removed one vertex because: the more I remove vertices, the less edges I will obtain.

Thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680559/proving-an-inequality-when-a-graph-is-not-connected/2680570#2680570

Comment: greedoid's link will give you an answer, but I also wanted to note some problems with your argument. First, when you write $Y=\{v|v\in V\}$, that means $Y=V$ in set theoretic language. What you should say is $Y=\{v\}$ for some $v\in V$, which means $Y$ contains only $v$. You also need to argue why partitioning the vertex set into $X$ and $Y$ like that will give the most edges.

Comment: Dear Kevin, thank you for your answer in fact I wrote in the way you proposed but my topic was edited. By the way in case it's not considered as admitted  I will prove this by saying that If I consider a graph with 2 component X and Y such that |X| (= p)  > |Y| ( = q) then if i remove one vertex from X so as to add it in the set Y the number of edges of this new graph will be lower because ${p-1}\choose{2}$ + ${q+1}\choose{2}$ <= ${p}\choose{2}$ + ${q}\choose{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

If the graph is not connected, then we can write $V=X\cup Y$ where $X,Y$ are non-empty and disjoint and there is no edge between vertices in $X$ and vertices in $Y$. While you are right that ultimately the numerically "worst case" does happen when $Y$ (or $X$) has only one element, you cannot assume in your proof that the sets do have this property to begin with. The structure and size of possible $X,Y$ is iven by the (given, arbitrary) graph and for a concrete graph may exclude that one of them has only one element. So in your proof, you will at some step have to show ${k\choose 2}+{n-k\choose 2}\le{n-1\choose 2}$ for **all** $k$ with  $1\le k\le n-1$.

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you for your answer. I thought I could majorate this value |E| regardless  of the given graph ( I wanted to say that |E| $\in$ [0, Max_Value] and by removing only one vertex and considering the partition (with a number of vertices greater than one ) as a complete graph, I will find this Max_Value.